# Is there a way to attach or anchor two QWidgets together?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qwidget

I'm getting started with Qt and decided to build a full-screen text editor. I want to have a button (button with arrow in screenshot) attached to a QDockWidget which opens and closes it so the button is always visible to the right side of the screen and stay anchored to it when dock is visible or resized.

My current app is a simple fullscreen textEdit set to centeralwidget in Mainwindow.

I haven't found a way to do this yet with layouts or existing addAnchor() functions so any help or direction is appreciated.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by using a container for your text edit and the button. A QWidget instance can be used as an "invisible"*** container for other widgets.

So in Qt Designer you add a `widget` as a central widget of the main-window, inside this widget you add the text edit and the button, then you set a vertical layout for this container widget.

Don't forget to restrict the docking widget to only dock to the right side, you can do that with: `dock->setAllowedAreas(Qt::DockWidgetArea::RightDockWidgetArea);` //assuming `dock` is the pointer to your QDockWidget.

In case you want the dockWidget to be able to dock to any side and the button to follow, you can do that too, but it get a little bit more complicated. Basically you need to connect a slot to [dockLocationChanged](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdockwidget.html#dockLocationChanged) of your dockWidget and based on where it's docked you need to set-up a new layout for the container widget to be vertical or horizontal and the order of the textEdit and the button based on the side the dock happened.

LE:*** you will most likely need to set the margins you want, since both the widget and it's layout can have them and the actual content might have higher spacing than you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried using the "invisible" layout method and it works well. But the problem then is there's space or a margin between the dock and the button and I can't seem to be able to get rid of it due to Qt's handling of layouts and margins. Anchoring the button to the dock was still my preferred method (if it exists) but it looks like I might just have to do away with the button all together.

Comment: Well, play with the margins until you get the result you want. 
If you attach the button to the dockWidget, it is going to be hidden when you hide the dockWidget.

Comment: Yep I finally got it to work exactly as I wanted by specifying the margins in the design tab (I was trying to specify it in the code before). Thanks for all the help!

Comment: You are welcome!

Setting those from code should work just fine, it doesn't matter from where you set the margins (it eventually calls the same functions anyway). But you probably missed setting the margins for some widget/layout.